# how to create a secure login with ASP.NET and MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, authentication

coming from php and Mysql i know how its best done in php but im not realy sure were to start with ASP.NET, can anyone give me any pointers?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you need to know how to make the form, lock down the site pages, store the username and passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [MySql Membership and role providers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx) as a starting point. For a more basic starting point, take a look at the [ASP.NET security tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/security).